# Applying column names to pandas DataFrame, names no longer unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, unicode

I have created a DataFrame full of zeros such as:

```
      0    1    2
0     0    0    0
1     0    0    0 
2     0    0    0
...
n     0    0    0
```

I have a list containing names for the column in unicode, such as:
`list = [u'One', u'Two', u'Three']`

The DataFrame of zeroes is known as `a`, and I am creating a new complete DataFrame with the list as column headers via:

`final = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=[list])`

However, the resulting DataFrame has column names that are no longer unicode (i.e. they do not show the u'' tag).

I am wondering why this is happening. Thanks!

Comment: If check `print  df.columns.tolist()`  no unicode?

Comment: It is unicode after this check - my other dataset unfortunately has leftover `u''` tags in column names leading me to believe this was an issue. Thanks!

Comment: Do _not_ use `list` as a variable name. It's the name of a list constructor.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason for lost unicode, you can check it by:

```
print df.columns.tolist()
```

Please never use reserved words like `list`, `type`, `id`... as variables because masking built-in functions. Also is necessary add [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) for convert values to `numpy array`:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(0, columns=range(3), index=range(3))
print (a)
   0  1  2
0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0
2  0  0  0

L = [u'One', u'Two', u'Three']
final = pd.DataFrame(a.values, columns=L)
print (final)
   One  Two  Three
0    0    0      0
1    0    0      0
2    0    0      0
```

because columns are not aligned and get all `NaN`s:

```
final = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=L)
print (final)
   One  Two  Three
0  NaN  NaN    NaN
1  NaN  NaN    NaN
2  NaN  NaN    NaN
```

I think simpliest is use only index of `a DataFrame` if all values are `0`:

```
L = [u'One', u'Two', u'Three']
final = pd.DataFrame(0, columns=L, index=a.index)
print (final)
   One  Two  Three
0    0    0      0
1    0    0      0
2    0    0      0
```